# locating Header in ajax XMLHttp request?

Tags: ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

where i have to place the headers in ajax and XMHttp requests in POST method like

For example:
`headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", "tok261_biz_api.abc.com"); 
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD","1244612379");`

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'url',
    data: dataobject,
    cache:false,
    dataType:'json',
    success:onSuccess,
    error:function(xhr,ajaxOptions){
        alert(xhr.status + " :: "  + xhr.statusText);
                    }
       });
```

XMLHttp:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is jQuery 1.5 you could use the `headers` property:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'url',
    headers: {
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": "tok261_biz_api.abc.com",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": "1244612379"
    },
    data: dataobject,
    cache:false,
    dataType:'json',
    success:onSuccess,
    error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions) {
        alert(xhr.status + " :: "  + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

In previous versions you could use the `beforeSend` method:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'url',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID', 'tok261_biz_api.abc.com'); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD', '1244612379'); 
    }, 
    data: dataobject,
    cache:false,
    dataType:'json',
    success:onSuccess,
    error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions) {
        alert(xhr.status + " :: "  + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```